# Selenium prompting for download even if set to false

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This code was working just fine until last week.

---

I have set the following configs to my driver but now seems that the pref "download.prompt_for_download": False" its not working and theres a popup to choose the path to save the file (which I dont want to happen)

```
self.pasta_download_relativa = str(self.download_path.absolute())
    
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1,
        "download.default_directory": self.pasta_download_relativa,
        "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": False
    })
```

I was using ChromeDriverManager, switched to the driver.exe for Chrome 117.0.5938.88. I cleaned my cache and such, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using another browser like edge, probably this is due to some bug in this chrome version

```
edge_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    edge_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    edge_options.add_argument('--incognito')
    edge_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-software-rasterizer')
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    edge_options.add_argument('--disable-logging')  # Desativa o registro no console
    edge_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 1,
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.default_directory': str(self.download_path.absolute())
    })
```